# Осьминог(-)мутант

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, раздельно-дефис

Нужно ли ставить дефисы?

`Осьминог(-)мутант.`

`Камерамен(-)титан.`

А если наоборот?

`Мутант(-)осьминог.`

`Титан(-)(к, К)амерамен.`

И с какой буквы нужно писать вторую часть во втором примере?

Comment: Кто минусонул? Что-то не так в вопросе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все варианты **разные** и все можно объяснить правилами.

**Пример 1. Камерамен титан**

1. **Титан**  — архаический бог, **камерамен** — оператор.
   **Где род и вид?** Допустим, титан — это род , а камерамен — вид.  Титаны разные бывают. Тогда для нарицательных существительных запись такая: ***титан камерамен  и титан спикермен.***

**А если наоборот»:**  камерамен  — это род, а титан — вид. Камераменов много, и один из них титан.

Тогда получаются верными все записи,  **дефисные или раздельные.** Но это для нарицательных существительных.

2. В реальности мы чаще видим **раздельное написание**, в том числе с учетом имени, если ***Титан*** — это имя.

***Титан Камерамен?***  Почему оба слова с прописной буквы и раздельно?  Это можно объяснить так: имя собственное, состоящее из двух слов. ***Титан-Камерамен?***  Тоже имя, только через дефис.

Вот такая у нас **однозначная** орфография.

3. **А это практика:**

***Камерамен Титан***  — мягкая игрушка.

**Титан спикермен** спасает **титана камерамена**  — фильм.

**Титан Спикермен** спасает **Титана Камерамена** — фильм.

Новый улучшенный **титан Камерамен**, все серии — фильм.

**Титан-Камерамен** —  это самый крупный и сильный Агент из типа Камераменов  — текст.

Пример 2.  **Аналогичная ситуация  с осьминогом.**

Существуют разные **варианты,** например:

Советский мультфильм про ***осьминогов-мутантов.***  Дефис (приложение).

***Осьминог Мутант*** уничтожает города. Имя собственное. И т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Надо так, и только так:

> Осьминог-мутант.

> Камерамен-титан.

> Мутант-осьминог.

> Титан-Камерамен. (Здесь, как я нашёл, пишется через дефис, а *Камерамен* — имя. Понятно, что это словосочетание зависит от того, как разработчики считают, надо. В остальных случаях всё, однако, однозначно, сэр-пэр.)

> Титан Камерамен. (Так, есль-с Камерамен — один из каких-то титанов, мне отнюдь не известных.)

Comment: Спасибо. А слова _титан_ и _мутант_ всегда пишутся через дефис?

Comment: Если они в обыденном контексте, то, конечно, да. Если это названия персонажей, то нет.

Comment: Ладно, верю. Принимаю.

Comment: Я по правилу рассуждаю. Это, в конце концов, логика.

Comment: @Максим Это игра, фильм, оттуда названия.  Все бы хорошо, да только практически все пишут не по правилам, то есть раздельно.  Поэтому надо учитывать этот факт. Кроме того, там скорее имя Титан, а камерамен – нарицательное.  Доверяй, но проверяй)  Кстати, о каком правиле идет речь. Ссылка необязательна, а просто озвучить.

Comment: @Sharon Я не знаю, по какому правилу. Я ведь спрашиваю, а не отвечаю. В принципе, Титан — это больше имя, чем камерамен, согласен с вами. А почему в своем вопросе про образ титана в мифологии вы использовали бездефисное написание?

Comment: Ссылку дайте на вопрос, как я его найду. Вы не отвечаете, но принимаете ответ  – значит, знаете это правило. Вся ответственность на вас)

Comment: Камерамен титан.  У меня род + вид, как дерево береза.  Титан – архаический бог, камерамен – оператор.  Получаем:  оператор (род) + титан вид.  Операторы разные бывают, а у нас титан/бог.  А можно считать наоборот; камерамен – род,  титан – вид. В общем, разные комбинации и свободное письмо. Главное – они из разных категорий, как вам и указали.   С другой стороны,  я могу посчитать, что это единое понятие и написать через дефис (как в сложносоставном слове вопросы-ответы).  Выбираю удобную для мен форму письма и подбираю правило.

Answer (score 1):

Я нарушу немного вашу идиллию... Дело в том, что дефис ставится между словами сопоставимых категорий, однако тут слова из совершенно разных категорий. Камерамен - это профессия, кинооператор то есть. Титан... ну тут не очень понятно, что имеется ввиду, но скорее всего это нарицательное или эпитет, вроде как гигант мысли. Получается: этот кинооператор - гений, - тирешечка необходима, однако, а не дефис.

..Камерамен - титан. Или: ..титан - камерамен.

Этот камерамен - титан киноиндустрии.

С осьминогом и мутантом, если речь идет о ком-то с характерным признаком, то можно осьминог-мутант, но это скорее название класса существ из компьютерной игры или фантастического сериальчика. Однако, в большинстве классических примеров написание будет через тире, ввиду того, что классы слов не принадлежат к одной категории и написание через дефис, это как писать через дефис мягкое-теплое.

Проблема в том, что приведенное вами сочетание слов, явно нетипично, но понять в каком отношении друг к другу таки находятся слова, не представляется возможным, так как контеста нет. Так что если выдумываете абстрактные задания, вы хотя бы какой-то контекст давайте, а то так можно долго плодить розовых пони в стране Невидалии...

Answer (score 1):

Здесь возможно двоякое написание. Так в справочнике Розенталя говорится:

Дефис  н е   п и ш е т с я:

а) если предшествующее однословное приложение может быть приравнено по значению к определению-прилагательному, например: красавец мужчина (ср. красивый мужчина), старик отец, гигант завод (но при перестановке слов: завод-гигант).

В справочнике Лопатина,однако,  такие сочетания предлагаются писать через дефис.

в) сочетания с однословными приложениями, предшествующими определяемому слову, напр.: старик-отец, красавица-дочка, умница-сын, герой-лётчик, мудрец-писатель, проказница-мартышка, самодурка-мачеха, трудяга-следователь, профан-редактор, пройдоха-управляющий.

Comment: По-моему, _мутант_ и _титан_ не похожи на прилагательные. Но все равно плюс от меня.

Comment: Про прилагательные упоминает Розенталь .Лопатин же говорит, если приложение предшествует определяемому существительному, такие сочетания пишутся через дефис. Мудрец-писатель, герой-летчик. Здесь ведь тоже нет прилагательных. Что важно — так это инверсия.

Comment: Писатель-мудрец,  летчик-герой. Приложение на втором месте, а дефис остался.  А как же инверсия?   А ведь есть еще равноправные отношения между словами (без приложения), тогда тоже дефис. У Лопатина эта тема изложена не лучшим образом, всё перемешал.  И произносятся слова по-разному, да только никто не слушает и соответственно не слышит.  И вот нестандартная задача, как решать?  Я думаю, что здесь родо-видовые отношения, а не определительные.

Comment: @Sharon, летчик-герой, писатель-мудрец. Приложение на втором месте, пишем через дефис. Все по правилам. Что касается инверсии. Если следовать Лопатину, следует писать через дефис. По Розенталю раздельно. Зачем не сохранять дефис при инверсии?

Comment: У Лопатина все через дефис, как ни напиши. Вот у нас герои, а среди ни есть герой-лЁтчик. Вот у на летчики, а среди ни есть летчик-герОй.  Различать бы надо. А вот у нас нестандартная задача с тремя РАЗНЫМИ решениями, причем ни одно из них не соответствует реальной ПРАКТИКЕ письма (раздельное написание). Это игра с выдуманными персонажами, ОПРЕДЕЛИТЕЛЬНЫХ отношений там нет. Это РОДО-ВИДОВЫЕ отношения (трава-полынь и полынь-трава), где надо еще разобраться с родом и видом.  А вы даете решения по разным справочникам, а Лео уверенно пишет дефис. И это можно назвать решением?

Comment: Какое родо-видовое название может быть в сочетании мутант(-) осминог и камерамен(-) титан? Явно же оценочное значение.

Comment: Раздельное написание соответствует справочнику Розенталю.